# How to add header row of a row in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I just added checkboxes to a gridview programatically as following:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
   TableCell tbCell = new TableCell();
   CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
   tbCell.Controls.Add(cb1);
   gvr.Cells.Add(tbCell);
}
```

My problem is my header row doesn't get created. How can I programatically make this?

Check the gap in corner on the link to an image.

Thanks in advance

http://postimage.org/image/klvbbv1xh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HeaderRow.Cells.Add` property

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
   TableCell tbCell = new TableCell();
   CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
   tbCell.Controls.Add(cb1);
   gvr.Cells.Add(tbCell);
}

TableCell tbCell = new TableCell();
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
tbCell.Controls.Add(cb1);
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Add(tbCell);
```

Comment: how, can you give me an example ?

Comment: cant get gvr, it only lives withing the foreach scoope

Comment: hey, out of curiosity, if i want to add a new header, but i want it to be positioned between other headers, how do i do that?

Comment: Since Cells is of type TableCellCollection, you can use AddAt method to add cell at a specific position. see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells.Add where Gridview1 is control ID

```
TableCell tbCell1 = new TableCell();
CheckBox cb12 = new CheckBox();
tbCell1.Controls.Add(cb12);
Gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells.Add(tbCell1);

foreach (GridViewRow gvr in Gridview1.Rows)
{
     TableCell tbCell = new TableCell();
     CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
     tbCell.Controls.Add(cb1);
     gvr.Cells.Add(tbCell);
}
```